GitLab Missing Project Group and Project include relative paths and embedded images in markdown Pages site
I have created a Pages site with Markdown files on GitLab using their Pages feature.
My project site exists within a Project Group (with other relevant projects)
Within my Repo, When I define a relative path that links an image (or another Markdown file), the path should be: (/[assets folder]/[images folder]/image-file.png).That same path/link on my deployed Gitlab pages site should be: gitlab.[My Company].io/My Repo Group/My Repo/assets folder/image folder/image-file.png
Instead this is what's happening:
Instead, Gitlab is taking my file path — (/[assets folder]/[images folder]/image-file.png) — and calling this URL: gitlab.[My Company].io/assets folder/image folder/image-file.png...
GitLab is skipping my Project Group and Repo in the pathway and missing the file, which throws me a 404 (and doesn't embed the image).
I'm at a loss here. Any suggesting to help GitLab call the correct file path? Hoping I'm making a simple mistake.

_config.yml info:
url: http://gitlab.[My Company].io/My Repo Group/My Repo
baseurl: /My Repo Group/My Repo
I have tried many variation of pathways to embed images (and link other files). I have this problem when linking Markdown files as well. The path skips my Project Group and Project.
Docs Folder Example (Linking/reference other markdown files within a markdown file)
Within my repo — The path that should work is:  (/[docs folder]/[docs subfolder]/file.md).
What my deployed site links to based on that path: gitlab.[My Company].io/[docs folder]/[docs subfolder]/file.md
It skips my repo group and repo.
The relative path that works, but NOT FOR images is: (../[docs subfolder]/file.md)

what are you using to create your pages? Plain HTML, or a particular SSG? Where is your config file located?
